# Error: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

Tags: cleos, accounts, eosio.token, system-accounts

I am facing some error while running this command

```
cleos create account eosio eosio.bpay EOS6wFEd5JHuUHWtaV12mxnm1v9udPsdrB7LUy1mVFc8iYJNdDMaL
```

It show's the output given below

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

And when I run `cleos get account eosio` it shows different keys which are not in my wallet. Its a Developers key which is given in EOSIO Developers site.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means you do not have the correct permissions to run the command as the account `eosio`. You need to make sure that the private key for the `eosio` account is in your wallet. You can do that using the command:

`cleos wallet import`

After you have the private key in your wallet, you can check that it matches the public key that you have on record for `eosio` by typing:

`cleos wallet keys`

If the public key is there, then you can execute actions as the `eosio` account.